# How to match a path using neo4j cypher and in case part of it doesn't exist return the rest

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a Neo4j graph that looks something like this : (person:Person)-[:acted_in]->(movie:Movie)-[:played_in]->(country:Country)

I would  like to match the whole path using this query:

```
MATCH path = ((person:Person)-[:acted_in]->(movie:Movie)-[:played_in]->(country:Country)) RETURN NODES(path), RELATIONSHIPS(path)
```

but, here is the tricky part, I would also like to add a condition that if `[:played_in]` does not exist, just return the partial path: (person:Person)-[:acted_in]->(movie:Movie)

Thanks.

Comment: In your cypher, all of these are variables, there are no labels or relationship types, and it's not clear which of these variables are previously bound to graph elements, and which are new and meant to be matched to graph elements from this match. It's easy enough to match up to 2 relationships with variable-length paths: `MATCH path = (start)-[*..2]->(end)`, but it's not clear from your question if this is what you need, or if you're working with specific labels and relationship types. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Added some labels hope it makes the question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like the following query will be useful for you :

```
MATCH path = (a)-[:b]->(c) 
OPTIONAL MATCH path2 =(c)-[:d]->(e) 
RETURN 
   NODES(path)+COALESCE (NODES(path2),[]), 
   RELATIONSHIPS(path)+COALESCE (RELATIONSHIPS(path2),[])
```

Comment: Works great! didn't know about COALESCE

Comment: Cool! but do not forget  to think about the @inverseFalcon comment and variable length path.